Oracle SQL summing columns and displaying the totals at the bottom of the list
I'm using this to create total for each cost value:
SELECT
    ITEM_NO
    COST_1,    
    COST_2,
    COST_3,
    COST_4,   
    SUM(COST_1)  over (order by loan_no rows unbounded preceding ) COST_1_TOTAL,
    SUM(COST_2)  over (order by loan_no rows unbounded preceding ) COST_2_TOTAL,
    SUM(COST_3)  over (order by loan_no rows unbounded preceding ) COST_3_TOTAL,
    SUM(COST_4)  over (order by loan_no rows unbounded preceding ) COST_4_TOTAL
FROM data

it creates this:

I'd like to have it look like this:

Is this possible. I'm not sure where to begin...
As always, any advise would be appreciated.

Use GROUP BY and ROLLUP:
SELECT ITEM_NO,
       SUM(COST_1) AS cost_1,
       SUM(COST_2) AS cost_2,
       SUM(COST_3) AS cost_3,
       SUM(COST_4) AS cost_4
FROM   data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(item_no)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE data (item_no, cost_1, cost_2, cost_3, cost_4) AS
SELECT 1057, 8111.73, -8600, 1550, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(8,2)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1693, 7856.25, -8600, 1575, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1701, 5206.20, -8600, 2000, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1784, 6002.97, -8600, 1900, NULL FROM DUAL;

Which outputs:



ITEM_NO
COST_1
COST_2
COST_3
COST_4




1057
8111.73
-8600
1550
null


1693
7856.25
-8600
1575
null


1701
5206.2
-8600
2000
null


1784
6002.97
-8600
1900
null


null
27177.15
-34400
7025
null



fiddle

Very nice!  Thanks, this is super helpful.     Can this be expanded to more items in the select statement, so that I still get one total at the bottom of the  list. Using the GROUP BY with more than one Field, gives sub-totals for each additional field.

@C0ppert0p Do you mean something like fiddle?

Indeed!! It took me few minutes or so to understand out how grouping_id was supposed to work. I added two more fields and it still works like a charm!
